# What happens if you allocate memory in a process once it has crashed?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have been working with [Google breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) for crash reporting for sometime. One of the things that it emphasizes is that one should not allocate memory once a process has crashed. It says it isn't 'safe' to allocate memory in a process once it has crashed.

What exactly is the meaning of 'safe' here?

Comment: How do you allow the program to execute, and then allocate memory after it has received a SIGABRT?

Comment: It's possible! You can set handler for SIGABRT and SIGSEGV and allocate memory there. I used that method to show BSOD with stacktrace in QT app. After calling `new QWidget` and displaying necessary info I just end crashed thread into infinite loop with `sleep(1)'.

Comment: @loentar Ofcourse it doesn't say you can't allocate memory. From what I know Microsoft's minidump process allocates memory. But this crash reporting engine explicitly warns from doing so.

Answer (score 4):

It's not safe because the standard library may be in a corrupt state, causing a second crash when you for more memory.

If you want to print something, do it w/o memory allocation (e.g. use local variables)

Comment: This is the only correct answer here. The crash handler will be the SIGSEGV signal handler. Stack use is fine, because it hets its own stack frame, but the heap may be in an incorrect state, so memory allocations might trigger a second crash.

Comment: Are we reading the same question? "It says it isn't 'safe' to allocate memory in a process once it has crashed. What exactly is the meaning of 'safe' here?" (Although your response is pretty much correct too. Must have missed it on my first reading.)

Answer (score 3):

Once a process has crashed, the best you can hope for is learning what has happened before exiting the process for good. The "safety" is, therefore, reduced to your error reporting code not causing a crash of its own on top of the original crash. That is why your options at this point are limited: for example, trying to allocate memory is dangerous, because the original crash could have been caused by corrupted heap.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be doing *anything* too complicated after a crash, lest you hang or have a crash in your crash code.  The two main reasons are: locks and global variables.   If your process crashed while holding a lock, and you need that lock for whatever you are doing after the crash, it'll either error off, or worse, hang.  There are also lots of state information stored in global variables. Not just what's declared in your program, but also lots of things used by libraries and even the dynamic linker/loader.  If any of those are bad, the result of calling a function that uses one of those globals is unpredictable.